# принт-сервер armbian orange pi pc2

Tags: linux, orange-pi

подскажите: делаю принт-сервер для принтера hp designjet t520 на базе armbian и мини-пк orange pi pc2. передача данных по wi-fi сети (railink 7600u). есть проблемы: нет драйвера ppd к принтеру, usb-ip, ipp-everywhere, hp pcl6 не работают. принтер, даже после перепрошивки, не понимает передачи данных по usb, только rj45. cups не понимает принтер, hp lip не понимает принтер. в настройках windows принтера для принт-сервера ставил-generic network card, hp jet direct-передача данных идет, только при выборе microsoft color publisher принтер-передает файл с нормальным весом, но там ограничение размера листа до А3. идею с перенаправлением портов rpt пробовал, но не получилось. есть ли какие-то универсальные способы/протоколы общения принтеров на linux и windows-компьютеров? как настроить в windows обманку компьютера на принт-сервер с линукс? есть у кого-то такие же, но удачные примеры c другими мини-пк на linux(orange pi, raspberry, odroid) или подобных?

Comment: Так у принтера есть сетевая дырка, зачем это вот все?

Comment: @gpg, чтоб не тянуть к нему провод, я подозреваю...

Comment: Я бы копал в сторону настройки cups'а, а потом расшарил бы принтер по самбе... на win в таком случае обычно используют нативные дрова... для cups'а [вот здесь](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/DesignJet-Large-Format-Printers-Digital-Press/Looking-for-a-Linux-Driver/td-p/6743710) советуют дрова от t120 использовать...

Comment: если дело действительно только в том, чтобы провод не тянуть и использование принтера как сетевого приемлимо, то можно просто сделать из апельсинки сетевой мост...

Comment: вся сеть организации сделана на wi-fi. драйверы, ссылки на которые вы скинули-это для windows.  gbg, какая сетевая дырка: lpr/lpd, hp jet direct? fat-zer, как можно сделать сетевой мост? в самом принтере есть веб-сервер и веб-службы, но есть проблема с размером файлов-файлы с графикой весом под 100Мб печатаются очень долго за счет передачи по wi-fi и обработки плоттером. идея была прикрутить принт-сервер для увеличения мозгов у принтера и дело в шляпе, но реальность оказалась страшнее... принт-сервер не захотел покупать, решил взять то, что валялось дома-orange pi pc2, для него нет раб. дроида